# how populate model with server data using backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am a beginner in backbone.js . I have a model with attributes and a collection referenced to that model. I need to fetch data from back end and populate model with those data. But I am not able to do it.

Data coming from server is :

```
[{"aaData":
  [
    {"customer_id":2,"bom_id":19,
      "bom_name":"Anonymous123",
      "bom_description":"Anonymous123",
      "last_modified":"2014-02-13 12:15:54.0",
      "bom_status":"d",
      "version":1,
      "pu_id":1},

     {"customer_id":3,"bom_id":20,
        "bom_name":"bom_idea_AU",
        "bom_description":"mfsBomIdea",
        "last_modified":"2014-02-13 12:16:46.0",
        "bom_status":"d",
        "version":1,
        "pu_id":2}
  ],
  "customerId":"",
"bomId":"",
"bomName":"",
"bomDescription":"",
"lastModified":"",
"version":"",
"bomStatus":""}
]
```

Code so far:

```
  var bomRecordModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
                    customerId: "",
                    bomId: "",
                    bomName : "",
                    bomDescription: "",
                    lastModified: "",
                    version: "",
                    bomStatus: ""

                },

});
var bomRecordObj = new bomRecordModel();


var bomRecordCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : bomRecordModel,
            url: "/easybom/easybom?opcode=6&pu_id=0"
});
var brcObject =  new bomRecordCollection(); 
brcObject.fetch();
```

Ideally it should return two models after fetching data

model1:

```
{"customer_id":2,
"bom_id":19,
"bom_name":"Anonymous123",
"bom_description":"Anonymous123",
"last_modified":"2014-02-13 12:15:54.0",
"bom_status":"d",
"version":1,
"pu_id":1}
```

model2:

```
{"customer_id":3,
"bom_id":20,
"bom_name":"bom_idea_AU",
"bom_description":"mfsBomIdea",
"last_modified":"2014-02-13 12:16:46.0","bom_status":"d",
"version":1,"pu_id":2}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aprse the response from your server:

```
var bomRecordCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : bomRecordModel,
            url: "/easybom/easybom?opcode=6&pu_id=0",
            parse: function(response){
                return response.aaData;
            }
});
```

Comment: thanks @David..I am able to get collection of models.

Comment: But I am not able to access the model using index i.e collectionObj.get(index)...Instead some default ID for each model is getting set implicitly (in my case c3,c4,c5..) n I have to use  collectionObj.get('c3') to access model. How to set or get id of each model?

Comment: In your model, you need to add `idAttribute: customer_id` so that Backbone knows what the id attribute is (default is `id`).